# Memory leak while assigning rootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

There is a 100% of memory leak shows by instrument at `self.window.rootViewController= navigationController;`. Application uses ARC.
`UINavigationController`,`UIViewController` and window are all properties have attribute strong.
How can i fix this leak.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    txnObserver = [[InAppPurchaseObserver alloc] init];
        txnObserver.delegate = self.viewController;
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:txnObserver];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
        **self.window.rootViewController= navigationController;**
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```

Same code did not show any leak in iOS 6 but it shows leak in iOS 7.

Updated question on 2013/10/10 with details.

Comment: So the leak is on that line. But what object is leaking?

Comment: Did you get any error message? like - message sent to deallocated insatnce? or some other error message? Also reply if the app crashes unexpectedly?

Comment: memory leak is shown at **self.window.rootViewController= self.navigationController;**

Comment: actually it is shown by instrument but instrument does not tell about exact line of leak. I couldnt  understand the real cause if leak.

Comment: @Steven Fisher actuallu i am new to iOS development. i am not getting the object which cause leak. but as i told instrument shown that line.

Comment: Don't forget removing NSNotification observers and invalidating NSTimers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` by this following code without @property of viewController :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

with `@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController;` :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It is not working for my code. Actually viewController is used at other place as well so i must make property for viewController.

Comment: I could not understand exact issue but your proposed solution is not working for me. It still shows memory leak.